# How to convert JSON string to SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, json

I want to create a table that will generate this kind of JSON string:

```
{
    "imagename": "Picture1",
    "date": "03.09.2014",
    "customer": {
    "customernumber": "8",
    "name": "any customer name"
  }
}
```

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: no, i dont need any code for this, just table schema for sqlserver

Comment: because i want to create table for storing those values and when i convert sql to json it should be like this

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Create the table as is but exclude the field customer, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aTable](
    [ImageName] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Date] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [CustomerNumber] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Select data from the table and create a dynamic object to assign the data (hard coded values as example):

```
var dyna = new {imageName = "Picture1", date = "03.02.2014", customer = new {customerNumber = "8", name = "any cust name"}};
```

Then serialize the dyna object using a JSON serializer.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me on this. it worked for me. great efforts